# Setting up a Windows timer, access denied

Tags: c++, windows, timer

I'm having trouble setting up the callbacks/windowproc of a Windows timer. What I'd like in this example is for the console window to show three "Timer Click!" messages and then quit.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <strsafe.h>
#include "Windows.h"

using namespace System;

int receivedCalls = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(
    HWND hwnd,          // handle to main window 
    UINT msg,       // type of message 
    WPARAM  wParam,     // additional information 
    LPARAM  lParam     // additional information
)
{

    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_TIMER:
        receivedCalls += 1;
        Console::WriteLine("Timer click!");
        return 0;
    }
}

int main()
{
    UINT result;
    UINT_PTR IDT_TIMER1 = 1;
    HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
    result = SetTimer(hwnd,IDT_TIMER1,5000,(TIMERPROC) NULL);
    if (result == 0)
    {
        LPTSTR lpszFunction = TEXT("SetTimer");
        LPVOID lpMsgBuf;
        LPVOID lpDisplayBuf;
        DWORD dw = GetLastError();

        FormatMessage(
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM |
            FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS,
            NULL,
            dw,
            MAKELANGID(LANG_NEUTRAL, SUBLANG_DEFAULT),
            (LPTSTR)&lpMsgBuf,
            0, NULL);

        lpDisplayBuf = (LPVOID)LocalAlloc(LMEM_ZEROINIT,
            (lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpMsgBuf) + lstrlen((LPCTSTR)lpszFunction) + 40) * sizeof(TCHAR));
        StringCchPrintf((LPTSTR)lpDisplayBuf,
            LocalSize(lpDisplayBuf) / sizeof(TCHAR),
            TEXT("%s failed with error %d: %s"),
            lpszFunction, dw, lpMsgBuf);
        MessageBox(NULL, (LPCTSTR)lpDisplayBuf, TEXT("Error"), MB_OK);

        LocalFree(lpMsgBuf);
        LocalFree(lpDisplayBuf);
    }
    while (receivedCalls < 3) {
        Sleep(100);
    }
    KillTimer(hwnd, IDT_TIMER1);
    return 0;
}
```

The MessageBox error code came from a windows page. I get an error code 5: access denied. What are the possible reasons that I wouldn't be able to set a timer? Do I really need administrative access to set a timer? If so, what is the preferred method for checking something periodically (for example, polling a website for new information).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's accurate.  The console window is owned by a completely different process, conhost.exe.  It acts as a security boundary, mostly to ensure that programs cannot do stuff like stealing passwords from the screen buffer.  Defeats this too, it just can never work as intended.  The actual window procedure is built into conhost.exe, it will not know what to do with those WM_TIMER messages.

You'll have to re-think this.  Like creating your own window and message loop, typically on another thread to prevent it from interfering with normal console I/O.  Or more easily by using [CreateTimerQueueTimer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682485(v=vs.85).aspx), beware that its callback runs on another thread.  Necessarily so since there isn't any way for the OS to break into your main thread.  The difficulty of doing this correctly provides insight in why a native Windows program works the way it does.  The message loop is the universal solution to the [producer-consumer problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem).  A console mode program does not attempt to solve it.